# Angular ui-router resolve, http success, stateParams

Tags: php, angularjs

My goal to achieve is:

first to insert new database record with http post, resolve with stateProvider and grab the new id and change view and stateParams.

i have this code for my http post service

```
myApp.service('postService', ['$http', function($http) {
this.insertNew = function() {
     $http.post('create_new.php')
    .success(function(data) {
        return data;
    });
};
```

create_new.php returns the ID like this (it works, proved with console)

```
return json_encode($data);
```

and the stateProvider looks like this (section)

```
 $stateProvider
 .state('newRecord', {
    resolve: {
        newArtID: ['postService',
            function(postService) {
                 return postService.insertNew();
        }]
    },
    params: {
        artID: <-- new ID from DB
    },
```

i did tests with stateParams in serval variations (in resolve and by params). how can i bring the new ID to stateParams, so i can access from the views?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Firstly, this seems like a bad idea. If you want to do this, you can create an abstract state above newRecord, do the resolve in there, then $state.go to the child state that has the parameter

Comment: I`m new to angular & use ui-router the first time.  I will try your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure your oder of operations is correct. `params` is for when you *already* have that data. You should return the data from your resolve, then you can access it in your scope, for ex:

Service:

```
.service('postService', function ($http) {
    this.insertNew = function () {
        return $http.post('create_new.php').then(function (data) {
            return data;
        });
    }
})
```

Route:

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('newRecord', {
            views: {
                "main": {
                    controller: 'SomeCtrl',
                    templateUrl: '...'
                }
            },
            resolvedId: {
                newArtID: function (postService) {
                    return postService.insertNew().then(function (response) {
                        return response;
                    });
                }
            }
        })
```

Controller:

```
    .controller('SomeCtrl', function (resolvedId) {
        var newID = resolvedId.id;  //depending on what is returned
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Meanwhile i did a workaround where works. But maybe i can use this in a other project.